# What is the .git/sequencer directory?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

I found a directory named `.git/sequencer`

Here is its contents:

```
$ ls
head  todo
$ cat head
d7d462cf3c0896aa09b3dec020cb21d4c4407d91
$ cat todo 
pick d7d462c Initailise repository
pick b88c8bb bash_funcs: add quote_args()
```

These `pick` lines make it look like it's the remnants of a `rebase` or `cherry-pick`, however:

```
$ git rebase --abort
No rebase in progress?
```

Can I safely remove this directory?

Comment: Both cherry-pick and revert use the sequencer. In a reasonably modern Git, `git status` will tell you that you are in the middle of one of these.

Answer (score 11):

This looks like the remnants of an incomplete `git revert`.

I used `git revert --quit` and the directory disappeared.

The [`git-revert` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert/) mentions this directory:

> SEQUENCER SUBCOMMANDS
>
> `--continue` Continue the operation in progress using the information in `.git/sequencer`. Can be used to continue after resolving conflicts in a
>   failed cherry-pick or revert.
>
> `--quit` Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.
>
> `--abort` Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.